# Terraform enable or disable a resource conditionally

Tags: apache-kafka, terraform, confluent-cloud

My requirement is to create or delete a resource by specifying enable flag true or false (In case of false the resource should get deleted, in case of true the resource should get created)

Kindly refer below code - here I am creating "confluent topic" resource and calling it dynamically using  for_each condition.

### Confluent Topic creation

topic.tf file:

```
resource "confluent_kafka_topic" "topic" {
  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.id
  }
  for_each         = { for t in var.topic_name : t.topic_name => t }
  topic_name       = each.value["topic_name"]
  partitions_count = each.value["partitions_count"]
  rest_endpoint    = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.rest_endpoint
  credentials {
    key    = confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.id
    secret = confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.secret
  }
}
```

Variable declared as:

```
variable "topic_name" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [{
    "topic_name" = "default_topic"
  }]
}
```

And finally executing it through DEV.tfvars file:

```
topic_name = [
    {
        topic_name  = "avro-topic-1"
        partitions_count = "6"
    },  
    {
        topic_name  = "json-topic-1"
        partitions_count = "8"
    },            
]
```

The above code execution works fine and I am able to create and delete multiple resources. I want to modify it further and add a flag/toggle to create or delete a resource.

Example as shown below:

```
topic_name = [
    {
        topic_name  = "avro-topic-1"
        partitions_count = "6"
        **enable = true #this flag will create the resource**
    },  
    {
        topic_name  = "json-topic-1"
        partitions_count = "8"
        **enable = false #this flag will delete the resource**
    },            
]
```

Kindly help suggest how it can be achieved and if there is any different approach to follow.

Comment: Can you try with `for_each = { for t in var.topic_name : t.topic_name => t if t.enable }`?

Comment: @MarkoE Comment-->answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I think this can be achieved with the following change:

```
resource "confluent_kafka_topic" "topic" {
  for_each         = { for t in var.topic_name : t.topic_name => t if t.enable }
  kafka_cluster {
    id = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.id
  }
  topic_name       = each.value["topic_name"]
  partitions_count = each.value["partitions_count"]
  rest_endpoint    = confluent_kafka_cluster.dedicated.rest_endpoint
  credentials {
    key    = confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.id
    secret = confluent_api_key.app-manager-kafka-api-key.secret
  }
}
```

Additionally, `for_each` should probably be at the top of the resource block to make sure it is visible immediately to the reader. The `if t.enable` part will make sure that `for_each` will create a resource only when the variable key has the `enabled = true`.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I tried with suggested approach.

for_each = { for t in var.topic_name : t.topic_name => t if t.enable == "true"}

But getting an error:

This object does not have an attribute named "enable".

Any additional config needed?

Comment: Well, you have to have `enable` key and value defined in the variable, as you have show in your question.

Comment: I have defined my variable as below:

variable "topic_name" {
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

Comment: You have to have this `**enable = false #this flag will delete the resource**`.

Comment: Once again, you have given an example in your question already. That is the last code block in there.

Comment: Thanks much for your kind help.
My mistake, I could not understand in the first attempt - this is resolved now :)